Getting a return value of None when it works in all other situations in a function with parameters, variables, lists, etc
# Sample Code
import datetime

sample = {
    "Eat": [
        datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 13, 2, 0),
        datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 13, 3, 0),
        "2024-09-13 20:43:35.440898",
    ],
    "Sleep": [
        datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 13, 4, 0),
        datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 13, 20, 0),
        "2024-09-13 20:43:24.354440",
    ],
}


# This is the entire function that I am using
def SortObjectives(obj):
    temLis = []
    temDic = {}

    for i in obj:
        print(str(obj[i][0].time()))
        temLis.append(obj[i][0].time())

    temLis.sort()
    print(temLis)
    temCou = 0

    # Recursive Function
    def SortObjectivesR(count):
        for i in obj:
            print(count)
            print(str(temLis[count]) + " --From temLis)")
            if obj[i][0].time() == temLis[count]:
                temDic[i] = obj[i]

                print(len(temDic))
                print(len(obj))

                if len(temDic) == len(obj):
                    print("Here")

                    print(temDic)

                    return temDic
                    # Why does this return None when it has a literal value???
                    # Keep in mind that this function only does this when their are two items
                    # in the obj dictionary when their not in order
                    # It works when in order and when in the number of items is > or < then 2

                else:
                    count += 1
                    SortObjectivesR(count)
                    # return temDic - not part of original code

    print(SortObjectivesR(temCou))
    # How I find what it returns
    # Would put in return statement to save lines, but it returns None
    # Under the specific condition mentioned, the alteration of
    # Variables work just fine.

    return temDic


print(SortObjectives(sample))

I have tried changing the order of the items and number of items and testing it to see if it would recreate the issue. My hope with this was to see if there was a similarity that I could point out, but it is specific too what I have pointed out in the code. I don't get it at all, it makes no sense to me. I also tried returning simple values like just  a string into the return and it ended up as None as well.
Comments You May Skip Over:
Why does this return None when it has a literal value???
Keep in mind that this function only does this when their are two items
in the obj dictionary when their not in order
It works when in order and when in the number of items   is greater or lesser then 2
WOuld put in return statement to save lines, but it returns None
Under the specific condition mentioned, the alteration of
Variables work just fine.

It won't, of course.  If you take the else clause on the first iteration, then you call the function recursively, but you THROW AWAY THE RETURN VALUE.  The fact that the inner call returned something is lost.  I suspect you want return SortObjectivesR(count).

I created a sample code and ran it, but it worked in the sample code (on a separate file). I don't understand why it's so specific to the program I have made.

Yes, I want to recurse using that then return the value I return from that, it works in sample code, but will not work in main code. I do not understand why. What do you mean by "THROW AWAY THE RETURN VALUE". It runs through it everytime and its tested because it prints something out in it, but it still returns None.

The RECURSIVE call prints and returns a value, but it's returning it to the OUTER call in the else clause, which discards the value.  The OUTER call then falls through and returns None.  The print calls Sort...R.  THAT call uses the else and calls Sort...R again.  That inner call returns a value to the outer call, which discards it and returns None.  It's a common error in recursive calls.

It only fails when there's more than one item, because that's the only case where you recurse.

It works when their are over two items though, is there a reason for it only doing it with two items? the commented return statement in the else clause was for testing purposes. it is not apart of the original code

The FIX is to add a return to the recursive call.  Have you done that?

I am working through it, I think I understand, so basically when I recurse it has nothing to return and when the recursion gets the return it has no where to return too. Ok, I see that makes sense now thank you! I was a bit confused at first. Now that I look at it, it seems simple. Though I am still not sure why it did not work when it was with more items, but maybe it was because of the ordering that I used during testing

It is a simple error, but it has complications that made it difficult in retrospect. When running the program it seems as though it runs normally, so it is hard to notice what is wrong with the code at first glance, but after analyzing the recursion is without a return statement attached which means that the value returned from the recursion is lost and as no return was given on the last run through the function its value was None. Thank you, Tim Roberts!
